# Python regular expressions with OR function

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to extract the strings "981","1922","1849","1819" from both string 1 and string 2 in one regular expression.

```
 #string 1 
 :3:LKR5000->981:4:LKR1000->1922:5:LKR500->1849:6:LKR100->1819

 #string 2
 :1:LKR5000->981
 :2:LKR1000->1922
 :3:LKR500->1849:4:LKR100->1819
```

Written python code:

```
   firstNote=re.findall(':\d:LKR\w+\-\>(.*?)\:',strtosearch2,re.DOTALL)

   1000s=re.findall('LKR1000->(.*?)\:',strtosearch2,re.DOTALL)
   500s=re.findall('LKR500->(.*?)\:',strtosearch2,re.DOTALL)
   100s=re.findall('LKR100->(.*?)\n',strtosearch2,re.DOTALL)
```

Can anyone help me to complete the code?
Thank you

Comment: `/->(\d+)/g` Like this? https://regex101.com/r/YYpGls/1

Comment: Can you add precisions about what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=->)\d+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsB1H5/2)**

[See the code output here](http://rextester.com/ITKS88568)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=->)` - positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by `->`
- `\d+` - matches 1+ occurrence of digits

OR, use this regex:

```
(LKR\d+)->(\d+)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsB1H5/3)**

From this regex, for each match, you can extract the contents of Group 1 and check if it is `LKR1000`,`LKR500`,`LKR100` and get its corresponding value from group 2 of that match

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should word: `r"LKR\d+->(\d+)"`:

```
re.findall(r"LKR\d+->(\d+)",s1)
#['981', '1922', '1849', '1819']
re.findall(r"LKR\d+->(\d+)",s2)
#['981', '1922', '1849', '1819']
```